# ParcelJS - Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename

Tags: parceljs

I'm trying to work with on a static site using Tailwind, SASS and ParcelJS. Every two minutes I have to stop the dev server and restart because of this stupid error. What does it even mean? I've tried a bunch of different things from the force installing of node/packages to disabling virus protection and changing the read-only attribute. Absolutely nothing works!

My NodeJS is installed on the F drive too.

[image]

Comment: It's being very weird. It seems it does not like when I edit the code from the initial npm run dev. If I make changes and save it shows the above error. But if I undo those said changes it works again!